# How to perform Global search on account hierarchy to display related records

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, global-search, parent-to-child

I have an account with account hierarchy setup and there is one Custom object "Agreement" added as related list on the account. When, I search an account with an account name on global search I want all related agreement records of that account as well as of all account comes under the account hierarchy, to be displayed after search. How to achieve this in Salesforce?

For Example:

There is an account'A' with child accounts A1, A2, A3 under Account Hierarchy.
and there is a related object **Agreement** 'AG' on account 'A' and 'AG1', 'AG2', 'AG3' on Account A1, A2 and A3 respectively.

Ideally, the relationship should look like below:

```
                                          A->A1->A2->A3  (Account Hierarchy)  
                                                         
                                          |  |   |   | -> (Lookup relationship) 

                                          AG AG1 AG2 G3  (Agreement records of respective account)
```

So, now If I search on global search by account name of an account 'A' then it should give me list of all agreement records of account 'A' as well as 'A1', 'A2' and 'A3'.

can anyone help to achieve this functionality? How to perform this exactly?

Comment: Not sure if enabling Einstein search will allow it but you can give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that I know how to do this is to use a custom field on your Agreement object, and have a workflow rule fire every time that Agreement record is created and updated to pull in something like:

```
BLANKVALUE(Account.Parent.Name, Account.Name)
```

If you create this, you would then need to do a mass update (even a no data change update), to trigger this rule to fire.

That is probably not the solution that you are looking for, but that is the only way that I know how to handle that.

Comment: I want only agreements records to be displayed for all account falls under account hierarchy. I have no such requirement for creating any new record.

Comment: This wouldn't be a new record. It would be a new field on your existing record. You would just need to do a mass update to all Agreement records to populate the new field. The reason for the new field is that the search is looking at hard data, while a formula is referenced data. The search does not look at formula field results, but if you had a text field with a workflow field update, the end result would look the same to your users, but the text field would be searchable.